# Random writing order to output file?

Tags: c, file, pointers, output, fseek

I've written a program that writes information to a file. The output to the file is not in the order that I am expecting. I have a header line and three additional lines with numerical information. The header comes first following by the third, first, and second lines.

Note that the file is open in `a` mode, not `a+`. According to various sources, re-positioning operators like `fseek()` are suppose to be ignored. For a while I was actually getting the third line ***before*** the first line ***after*** that line was written. If the `fseek()` line is omitted, the third line actually is written before the header ..

If the `fseek()` function is left commented (regardless of being in `a` or `a+` mode) the output is as shown in the picture below.

I wrote in a bit of code to see how the output *should* be written. The text in the file is certainly not what it should be ..

I attempted to use the `fseek()` function to find the position just before the EOF before each write but to no avail.

**I have also noticed that if I use `fflush(writeP)` then I get the same effect that including the `fseek()` function would. The file is still out of order as shown, but the third line is no longer before the header line.**

What am I missing?

```
void quickSortHelper(int* num, long startTime, long endTime, int size){
FILE *writeP = fopen(QUICKSORT_FILE, "a");
    if(writeP == NULL){
        fputs("Error opening file\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

static int times = 0;
long deltaT; //change in time

if(size < STEPSIZE){//first time, write header to file
    printf("Writing header!\n");
    fprintf(writeP, " --- QUICKSORT ---\nCOUNT\tTIME\tMEDIAN\n");
}

deltaT = (clock() - startTime)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
//fflush(writeP);
fseek(writeP, -1, SEEK_END);

printf("Writing: %d\t%ld\t%d\n", size, deltaT, findMedian(num, size));
fprintf(writeP, "%d\t%ld\t%d\n", size, deltaT, findMedian(num, size));

if(++times == 3)
    fclose(writeP);

return;
```

}

[image]

With the `fseek()` line commented, the output is:

[image]

Comment: can you post more code? Is this part of a single function or where is the `return` coming from?

Comment: I posted a bit more to include the function arguments if that helps at all, but there really is nothing more to the program. Basically, I send this function the start and end times of the quickSort algorithm. The quickSort algorithm is called 3 times with an increasing number sorting requirements (shown in the left column of the output). This is the only file open at the time of writing. I call the function once and open the file in `append` mode. I return to the calling function with the file remaining open. After this function is called three times I close the file and exit.

Comment: Do you have to work within the file? i mean i would be massive amounts easier to pull the data out of the file and work with it in a buffer or something and than output it or write it back to the file and output it?

Comment: I just write to that file. The data that I sort is done how you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not close `writeP` the first 3 times when function is called. So, the file is opened by several `FILE` handles which get closed on exit.  The `"a"` works only for the same `FILE` handle or when data have reached the disk.

Comment: I tried opening the file only once but encountered a stranger problem. If I declare the FILE pointer and open the file inside some IF statement that evaluates true only during the first time the program is ran, I get only a single line of OUTPUT as if the file was closed or something. What you have said does make sense though. I have been working on other parts of this program too long today to even try and change it .. Thank you.

Comment: You mean `static FILE *writeP; if (!writeP) writeP = fopen(...);`.  This should work (but is ugly).  I suggest to open it outside and pass it as a parameter or global variable.

Comment: I tried that but the compiler complained that writeP was not constant.

Comment: really? Or did you tried `static FILE *writeP = fopen(...)` (which is forbidden)?

Comment: I think that is what I tried. How can the first suggestion be legal if the latter is not? With the first you declare the pointer as static and then change it. Is it that static data may be defined once?

Comment: @sherrellbc The initializer for a `static` variable must be a compile-time constant, which the return value of a function is not. (`static` does _not_ mean constant as in unassignable, in this context it means statically allocated in memory and not dynamically placed on the stack when the function is called, i.e., the same variable is shared for all calls to the function.)

Comment: C allows only constant initializers for `static` variables.  `static` storage is initialized to zero so I omitted an explicit `= NULL` in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that you open the same file on every function call, but only close it on the third call. I would suggest moving the file opening and closing logic out of that function, and passing the `FILE *` handle as an argument to the function; this would also avoid having to hard code the call number on which to close into that function.

So the place where you call the function would look something like this:

```
FILE *writeP = fopen(QUICKSORT_FILE, "w"); // "a" changed to "w"
if (!writeP) {
    perror(QUICKSORT_FILE);
    exit(1);
}
// perhaps write the header into the file here
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    // do the quicksort
    write_quicksort_results(writeP, …);
}
(void) fclose(writeP);
```